# Thread Context Switching Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a function that, for argument sake, has two lines of code.

```
Line A
Line B
```

Both lines are calls to third party web service that does some work. It appears as though the service call on Line B is contingent on being called immediately (time-wise) after the call to Line A. This all works fine in a non-threaded environment but my application is threading lots (potentially 100) of these calls.

The problem with this threading, I believe, is that the context switching between the threads is causing enough time (a very small amount of time) to elapse between the call on Line A and the call on Line B that it's causing the call on Line B to throw a custom soap exception.

My knowledge of threading doesn't really extend to a situation like this. Is there anyway to make sure the call on Line B happens immediately after the call on Line A without thread context switching occurring in between?

Comment: What custom SOAP exception?  Timings for a Webservice are never very predictable or stable. Seems unlikely that the server is measuring in (the low) milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need these lines to be called together then you can lock them, meaning that nothing else would enter this section until it is complete:

```
lock(lck)
{
    Line A
    Line B
}
```

However, this may cause you problems if this is all the 100 threads are doing - you lose your parallelism. In fact, whatever you do, if this is a general requirement, you will lose a degree of parallelism.

Comment: A more complex but more finely tuned approach would be using defined semaphones yourself. Especially if you need more fine-grained control.

Comment: Luckily the threading does do a lot of other things, and you're right, some parallelism will be lost but it will not eliminate the benefit of the threading since other work is being done. What would "lck" be in this case? I thought locking may be the answer, but I was unsure as to what to lock.

Comment: A static object declared within your class definition. This provides a simple lock on this part of code.

Comment: This does not prevent context switching (to threads not locking on lck or to other Processes).

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed the case, (and I suspect that you are wrong and it is not), that a small delay between these calls results in your system failing, then you are in big trouble.  As @Henk says, an OS entry on a hardware interrupt, (driver), can happen between A and B, adding a delay. If the driver interrupt makes another thread ready, A/B could be preempted at this time and generate much bigger delays.  If A and B are complex web service calls, it is almost inevitable that the services make many system calls internally, giving the OS even more chance to introduce delays/preemption.  Even if your A and B made no explicit system calls, a page fault could introduce a longish delay while the code/data/stack/whatever is paged in.

Try very hard to find some other solution to your problem than trying to ensure that B 'immediately' follows A  - I'm hopeful that you will find one!

Rgds,
Martin